# Can somebody explain this odd toString behavior?

Tags: java, tostring, behavior

I wrote a class representing a Polynom. `coefficients` holds the coefficients. `unknown` holds the `char` which represents the unknown.

What I expect when `coefficients` contains [2,2,3]: `"2x^2 + 2x + 3"`

Reality: `"122.0^2 + 2.0x + 3.0x"`

The code:

```
public class Polynom implements Comparable<Polynom> {
private ArrayList<Number> coefficients;
private int degree = 0;
private char unknown = 'x';
private String name = "P(x)";

public Polynom() {
    this("P(x)", 'x', null);
}


/**
 * Accepts Format: A1x^n + A2x^n-1 + ... + A(n-1)^1 + An 
 * @param coefficients - Number array of coefficients (varargs)
 */
@SafeVarargs
public Polynom(Number... coefficients) {
    this("P(x)", 'x', Arrays.asList(coefficients));
}

public Polynom(String name, char unknown, List<Number> coefficients) {
    this.name = name;
    if (coefficients != null)
        this.coefficients = new ArrayList<>(coefficients);
    else
        this.coefficients = new ArrayList<>();
    this.unknown = unknown;
    this.degree = this.coefficients.size();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name + '=');
    int cdeg = degree - 1;
    for (Number a : coefficients) {
        double absvalue = Math.abs(a.doubleValue());
        String sign = (a.doubleValue() > 0 ? " + " : " - ");
        if (absvalue > 1)
            if (cdeg != degree - 1)
                sb.append(sign + absvalue + unknown
                        + (cdeg > 1 ? "^" + cdeg : ""));
            else
                sb.append(absvalue + unknown + (cdeg > 1 ? "^" + cdeg : ""));
        else if (absvalue == 1)
            if (cdeg != degree - 1)
                sb.append(sign + unknown + (cdeg > 1 ? "^" + cdeg : ""));
            else
                sb.append(unknown + (cdeg > 1 ? "^" + cdeg : ""));
        else
            sb.append(sign + absvalue);
        cdeg--;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Polynom o) {...}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {...}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Polynom p1,p2;
    p1 = new Polynom(1,-2,3);
    p2 = new Polynom(2,2,3);
    System.out.println(p1+"\n"+p2);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, unknown holds the char which represents the unknown, I'll clarify.

Comment: You're using `int` or `double` ?

Comment: Can you show us where `coefficients` is defined? The actual type in there (I suspect a double) will help you debug this.

Comment: I'm using Number class.

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through your code to see what is happening at each step.

Comment: Please show a *short but complete* program demonstrating the problem. I'd also strongly encourage you to use braces for every `if` statement, even if the body is only a single statement.

Comment: I did. it just oddly goes wrong when It's being appended.

Comment: Any particular reason you use `Number` instead of int or double?

Comment: You should consider using braces.

Comment: So the user can use any type of number obviously :)

Comment: Which numbers work with `Number` but not `double`?

Comment: It's a good question, I was looking for the OOP solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to concatenate a `char` to a `number`, which results in addition instead of concatenation, since there is no `String` involved.

When you append `2+unknown` to your `StringBuilder`, you are appending `2+'x'`, which is `122` (since `120` is the numeric value of the character 'x').

Change your unknown from `char` to `String`.

```
String unknown = "x";
```

That's all you need to change.

Comment: Yeah I probably missed that